# Need tool to detect malware in several pdfs in Windows environment

Tags: windows, malware, pdf

I am looking for a Windows product that could detect malware in several pdfs in Windows environment. I don't want to use Python and I don't want to use Stream Dumpler. I am looking for something simple and effective. I wonder why most of the paid virus protection programs are useless in this regard?

Edit:
To calrify my objective, I want to identify the infected PDF files in a simple way given that I have several files and I don't care about how or why they got infected.
Thx.

Comment: Product recommendations are off-topic here, and you do not explain the problem with anti-malware programs. Did you try VirusTotal and it failed? Are you sure the PDFs are infected? To detect malware, you use anti-malware. If you don't want to use anti-malware, then you need to explain your scope.

Comment: And Malwr / Cuckoo sandbox which supports PDF files.

Comment: @schroeder, I want to be able to examine several PDF files not just a few. VirusTotal would not be practical since I have to upload files one by  one.

Comment: My VirusTotal comment was to highlight that there might be "paid virus protection programs" that would work for you. VirusTotal would show you what would be more reliable in your situation.

Comment: Voting to close this as per Schroeder, but also worth pointing out that you've not explained your objective here Is it to prevent infection? To detect the source of an infection? To analyse the malware....

Comment: @symcbean, all I want is to identify infected files. I don't care about further details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several options.

**1. online services**
You can use https://www.virustotal.com, https://malwr.com (you can also make a sample private) or one of these tools here:

http://www.malware-analyzer.com/#!document-analysis-tools/cw25

The people behind Malwr created Cuckoo sandbox, which is also used on Malwr. You can create also your own VM with Cuckoo sandbox and open the PDF file in its PDF file reader. http://www.cuckoosandbox.org/

For uploading multiple files at once to VirusTotal there is a tool: https://www.virustotal.com/de/documentation/desktop-applications/

**2. VirusTotal API**
VirusTotal has a public API which is documented here:
https://www.virustotal.com/de/documentation/public-api/
https://www.virustotal.com/de/documentation/public-api/#scanning-files
https://www.virustotal.com/de/documentation/public-api/#scripts-interact

I have created a small standalone tool which just needs Java installed and uses the VirusTotal API (you need an API key) to upload all files in the same directory.
https://github.com/DanielRuf/Plain-of-JARs/tree/master/JARs/virustotalscan
https://github.com/DanielRuf/Plain-of-JARs/tree/master/sources/virustotalscan

```
VirusTotalScan 1.0.0
Uploads all files in a given directory to VirusTotal using the VirusTotal API.
```

If you use it, please check the properties file and change the comment to `comment=`

Well, most tools are written in Python, Ruby or some other widely used language. You can easily install Python on your PC.

**3. ClamAV as alternative**
ClamAV has some rules which may detect it. There is ClamWin http://www.clamwin.com/

**4. send samples to antivirus vendors manually**
If you want to send the samples manually to the antivirus vendors, there are two mailing lists here: http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/how-report-malware-or-false-positives-multiple-antivirus-vendors.htm#Easily_Submit_Malware_To_All_Vendors

You just have to create a password protected zip file (better one per file, but one zip file for all PDF files should be also ok), click the link and send the attachment with your email client and wait for the responses.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Most of the tools you have proposed work by submiting a file at a time and that will not work in my case. As for ClamWin, I will give it a try, although it had some negatives listed here: http://www.pcworld.com/article/231520/clamwin_free_antivirus.html#comments

Comment: VirusTotal has an API which you can use to submit multiple files and read the reports later. I added the link to the updated answer.

Comment: that is something new to me. Thx.

Comment: Malwr has some unofficial API but it seems they paused the API. At least I could just use VirusTotal. I will link some more ressources for VirusTotal in the answer.

Comment: But personally I prefer Malwar (which uses Cuckoo) as they have much better results (more details).

Comment: Because VirusTotal just checks the hashes against the different antivirus vendors and sends the samples to them. You can do this manually if you want to. I added a section about this to the answer.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts in trying to assist me.

Answer (score 1):

Reading your question, I am not sure if you want to only detect and isolate, or you actually want to dig in and see if you can find the malware. In each case, you have an option:

Opt1: Setup a VM to isolate your main system and put a antivirus and run the pdfs through the antivirus in your VM. Also take note of the advice above and put them through virustotal to see if any other AV system has a signature for them.

Opt2: Setup a VM to protect your main system and then get some malware analysis tools. Some great ones include PEid, Dependency Walker and IDA Pro, however I believe these may work mostly with .exe files. However one great one that you should certainly use is "Process Explorer" for Windows. This will provide a very detailed view of all the processes running, including colour coding them depending on stages (i.e. starting, running or closing). As such this will show any new external connections your system is making as your pdf file is opening (this is more a dynamic analysis method rather then static). If your system is making external connections while your opening a pdf, this is a sign of malware in the pdf trying to connect with C&C or other server.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, although I wanted a tool to run using several files as input, your suggestion of Process Explorer sounds elegant. I hope it works, and I will give it a try. Thanks again.